# Vue JS Object Object in foreach component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following code:

```
  <tr v-for="item in companies">
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
  </tr>
```

Example of content in the Companies:

```
    companies:Array[30]
0:Object
address:Object
dateOfCreation:"2008-02-11T00:00:00"
dateOfDissolution:null
liquidated:null
name:"BBC LIMITED"
number:"06500244"
officerSummary:null

1:Object
address:Object
dateOfCreation:"2011-02-07T00:00:00"
dateOfDissolution:null
liquidated:null
name:"BBC AND CO LIMITED"
number:"07520089"
officerSummary:null
```

Which works, however I want to pass my item object to a child component:

```
    <company v-for="item in companies" :company="item"></company>
```

The child component is very simple:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class CompanyComponent extends Vue {
    props: ['company'];

}
```

and

```
<template>

    <div>
       Does it work?

        {{ company.name }}
        </div>
</template>

<script src="./company.ts"></script>
```

However the markup returned is 30 of the following:

```
<div company="[object Object]">
   Does it work?
    </div>
```

So clearly it is looping through 30 times, but not passing the object.

Now that only renders if I remove the `{{ company.name }}`, when I include that I get: **Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"** which I assume is because the object isn't actually being passed through.

So why am I getting [Object object] and why isn't my object passing through properly?

Comment: Do you use `vue-property-decorator` correctly? From its docs, you should import `Vue` from `vue-property-decorator` not `vue`

Comment: Have you checked in the Vue dev tools?

Comment: @connexo what am I looking for, the CompaniesComponent has data in the companies object, the loop generates 30 CompanyComponents, just the content doesn't pass through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an isolated set-up, the problem you've described doesn't occur.
The problem must be somewhere in your code or data that you haven't shown.

```js
Vue.component('company', {
  props: ['company'],
  template: '<div>name: {{company.name}}</div>'
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    companies: [{
      name: 'foo'
    }, {
      name: 'bar'
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <company v-for="item in companies" :company="item" :key="item.name"></company>
</div>
```